# Using 'table' and 'table-cell' with display property in responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, adaptive-design

[image: Using table and table-cell]

I am using `display: table;` on the container and `display: table-cell;` on the child elements, to highlight some posts horizontally on a page.

The thing is, I have no idea as to how to make them responsive, i.e. as the screen-size becomes smaller, each child (i.e. `table-cell`) should become proportionately smaller, whilst continuing to stay aligned horizontally.

How do I do this?

- Example Code: http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/dCLgq
- Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/full/dCLgq

Comment: Try adding `table-layout:fixed` on the container and `width:auto` on the children

Comment: @JanDvorak That didn't work. :-/

Comment: If you know the number of columns, setting an exact width should work: `width:25%` in case of four columns.

Comment: then you might not need `display:table` either

Comment: @JanDvorak I tried `width: 31%;` and `float: left;` on the child elements, and that seems to have done the trick. Is that what you suggested that I do? (Please add it as an answer, for others. I am going with braican's solution for now.) Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To scale the inner containers down with the page, you can set the container `div`'s width to `100%`:

in your example:

```
#the-big-stories {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;

    /** add 100% width **/
    width:100%;
}
```

further, if you want to scale the images with the child containers, just give them `width: 100%;` as well with `height:auto;`

see your codepen forked below:

http://codepen.io/braican/pen/xCmsw

You'll probably need to use media queries to really get the stuff inside to play nicely together, but the container will scale with the browser, as will the inner `div`'s.

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;` with `display: table;` solved my prob here. Thanks. :)